# How can I plot this function that has a fraction that has an absolute value in the denominator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions

I have this piecewise function:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{x^2-x-2}{|x-2|}, & x \neq 2 \\
0, & x = 2\text{.}
\end{cases}$$

I can't figure out how to graph it. I punched these numbers into my calculator, and it created a parabola, but I haven't been able to get there on my own without the calculator.

So far I have plotted the point $(2,0)$ on my graph, and I factored the first function to 
$\dfrac{(x-2)(x+1)}{|x-2|}$ 
and now I am stuck. I tried multiplying both the top and bottom by $x+2$, but after simplifying I ended up with $x+1$, which I am pretty positive is not correct.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**: recall (ignoring the $x = 2$ case):
$$|x-2| = \begin{cases}
x-2, & x-2 > 0 \\
-(x-2), & x-2 < 0 
\end{cases} = \begin{cases}
x-2, & x > 2 \\
-(x-2), & x < 2\text{.}
\end{cases}$$
So $$\dfrac{x^2-x-2}{|x-2|} =  \begin{cases}
\dfrac{x^2-x-2}{x-2} = \dfrac{(x-2)(x+1)}{x-2} = x+1, & x > 2 \\
\dfrac{x^2 - x - 2}{-(x-2)} = -(x+1), & x < 2\text{.}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Do I ignore the x=2 case when I graph this function?

Comment: @Grace When $x = 2$, $f(x) = 0$. This is by definition in the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Dividing the two cases:
$$
x-2>0 \iff x>2 \Rightarrow |x-2|=x-2
$$
and

$$
x-2<0 \iff x<2 \Rightarrow |x-2|=2-x
$$
your function become:
$$
f(x)=
\begin {cases}
y=-x-1 \quad , \quad x<2\\
y=0 \quad,\quad x=2\\
y=x+1\quad,\quad x>2
\end{cases}
$$

the graph is done  by two open half-lines ( decreasing for $x<2$ and crescent for $x>2$) and an isolated point $(2,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\frac{x}{|x|}=1$ for $x>$ and $\frac{x}{|x|}=-1$ for $x<0$.  Thus,

> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{(x-2)(x+1)}{|x-2|}=\text{sgn}(x-2)(x+1)}$$

where $\text{sgn}(x-2)=1$ for $x>2$ and $\text{sgn}(x-2)=-1$ for $x<2$.  We can define the sign function as $0$ when its argument is $0$. And we're done!